# How to delete multiple nodes in one request in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes from one root and I want to delete the data from both of them in one request. Both sub-nodes has the same key. I tried this:

```
Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase(<root_path>);

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put(<path_to_first_node>, key);
childUpdates.put(<path_to_second_node>, key);

listToRemoveRef.updateChildren(childUpdates, null);
```

But it removed data from only the first node

Comment: when I recompiled the project, the code above worked.

Comment: passing null to the value of childUpdates.put(<path_to_node>, null); seems to be more appropriate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `updateChildren` function wrong. What you want to do is this

```
Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase(<root_path>);

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("<path_to_first_node>" + key, null);
childUpdates.put("<path_to_second_node>" + key, null);

listToRemoveRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

The second parameter to `updateChildren` doesn't set the value to `null` it is an optional completion listener ([see documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener))). So instead of passing `null` to it on the last line, you can just omit it.

Comment: the question is three years old, so it might have changed by that time :)

Comment: No, actually your usage of `updateChildren` was wrong both then and now -- [the second parameter is and was for "completion callback"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback). The code in your question suggests that you want to use the second parameter to set the value null since you are passing keys instead of values in your map of updates. So if you think that your question is obsolete, you should delete it otherwise you might find this answer useful.